How to add paypal pay button in every product page
I set the following option to true in the admin portal:
Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> PayPal -> Display on Product Details Page
After this, the pay button did not appear.

Have you configured the paypal as well? Also run caching and all commands?

I have configured PayPal (the PayPal button is enabled on the last checkout page), and I have followed all caching procedures.
